# Error in using 'theano-nose' command

Tags: theano

After installing Theano from Enthought Canopy on Windows, following the steps here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#id9 , I tried to execute the command theano-nose from Canopy terminal. I got an error message saying "unable to find theano-nose". Can someone tell me what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

theano-nose is from the command line. But your shell need to be able to find it.

It is highly possible it didn't got installed correctly on Windows or that you need to reboot or log out/log in. I do not remember Windows particularities on that level.

But a simple work around is to start python and run this:

```
import theano
theano.test()
```

This is equivalent for what you want to do.